# Completely formatting default button

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the requirement to format completely the default button in bootstrap 3. I have already changed the default background color in the customizer.

Yet I don't know where to change the formatting for the different button states (active, hover, focus). Does somebody know where I have to do the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the styles responsible for default button hover,active,focus state...change it accordingly.

```
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  background-image: none;
}
```

What exactly happening is that customizer darkens the background color by 10% and border color by 12%.

```
Less Mixins.
 background-color: darken(@background, 10%);
 border-color: darken(@border, 12%);
```

So there is  no way for you to change color entirely in the customizer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the customizer, the border-radius and border-color, as well as hover and active pseudo-classes are automatically calculated (using LESS), relative to the background color. If that's not what you want, you can change them each independently:

```
.btn-default:hover{
  background-color:#eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color:#999;
  etc...
  }

.btn-defauot:active{
  background-color:...etc
  }
```